# could not convert varchar to datetime in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

In my database i got problem when converting varchar to datetime due to different format of datetime as per below.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

I have 2 select clause as per below

> Select Getutcdate()
>   Select top 1  localmachinetime from perfmon

both return following format respectively

> 2012-05-28 06:54:45.753>
>
> 28-05-2012 03:03:07

and when i try to convert it to datetime using CAST then it gives me error in second case as per below.

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

Comment: post your cast query what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx?ppud=4) with a Date/Time style.

```
convert(datetime, '28-05-2012 03:03:07', 105)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply it works well but is there any solution by which i can convert to 105 irrespective '28-05-2012 03:03:07' (2nd parameter) format, it will be different in mine case

Comment: Are you saying that `localmachinetime` in table `perfmon` has stored the `datetime` values as a string in **different** formats?

Comment: What do you mean "to 105"? The code converts *from* 105 string format *to* `datetime`.

Comment: Oh means 105 represent this format '28-05-2012 03:03:07'? I am not sure about what will be the format there, it will be any in mine case.

Comment: You can use the above code to convert from string to datetime if you **know** that the date format in the string is `dd-mm-yy`. That is what `105` does. If you want to convert from other formats you have to use a different style. If you for some reason needs to store a datetime as a string you should use `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm` as a format for the value.